# Run init.d script conditionally based on hostname

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting, newrelic

What would be the best way to conditionally run an init.d script on linux based on hostname? I'm working with New Relic and some of the servers simply don't need it installed, but they're all otherwise basic copies of one another. This is Ubuntu.

I've tried (and failed) to put in a host conditional but for the life of me I can't get it working. Threw exits in the top of the file as well as in the start function, but it seems to fire up every time. Without knowing completely how those scripts are fired I'm a little confused on how to alter it to not fire if it server name isn't something like production, etc.

Any guidance would be super helpful.

Comment: An `exit` in the script should be more than enough to prevent it from actually doing any work. That won't prevent it from being attempted though. What, specifically, did you try? And what, specifically, did you see that made you think it didn't work?

Comment: "I've tried (and failed) to put in a host conditional but for the life of me I can't get it working." We can't get it working either without seeing what you've actually tried. Also, I'm not familiar with the Ubuntu/Debian init system, but I know `/bin/sh` is `dash`. Maybe your shebang is `/bin/sh` but you're using bashism in your script, e.g., `[[`?

Comment: This is ***horrible*** practice. You'd either make the init script unupdateable or if you make a custom package, you have unnecessary code for most of your servers. Either use puppet or chef instead or above your image copies or disable NewRelic by default and activate it manually or simply install it manually. Another option would use kickstart files instead of images. Everything is better than fiddling with init scripts, especially if you don't know enough about them to have to ask this question.

Comment: I'm with Mahlberg now. Though I haven't come up with an automated solution yet, I've backtracked on editing the init.d files and started working on a different solution for which I haven't yet to fully suss.

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of the script you would like to disable:

```
if [ $(hostname) != "goodhost" ]
then
  exit
fi
```

replacing "goodhost" with the actual name of the host where the script is supposed to run.

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Which would either render the initscript impossible to update or this expected behavior would be overwritten on update. Simply disabling the init script on all machines except `goodhost` or manually installing it there is the way better solution. Downvote as this is just a temporary solution.

Comment: The user did not ask for a permanent solution or for advice on what good practice is. The immediate concern was that he could not get his init script to not run on a particular host using the crude technique. The answer was meant to help him debug his technique. If he is able to get the above to work, for a long term solution he can, for example, have a post-update script that inserts the above into his scripts.

Comment: On a package provided by new relic? I doubt that.